# Technique of Substitutions in Inequalities

Tags: inequality

I was recently going through the [IMO 2000 Problem 2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h57603p354109), which is an inequality problem where people have used substitutions to solve. Now, I often come across these types of substitutions to solve Olympiad Inequalities. But I'm not able to think of them myself. I always think what's the "thought process" or "motivation" of deriving such substitutions. I know these varies from question to question, but in general how do I get better at the technique of substitutions in Olympiad Inequalities? It would be really beneficial if you can suggest some references (handouts/book/any type of resources) to get to know more deeply about this. Thank you

Comment: Like most "why does this technique work", it generally boils down to one of 1/ Experience 2/Seeing it has worked in similar cases, 3/ Because it simplifies the statement, 4/ Luck.

Comment: As mentioned above, there is no rule that a technique is surely going to work.  The form of a condition / constraint may suggest a substitution which can remove / simplify the the constraint - e.g. the "Ravi substitution".   Or the terms of the inequality could be made univariate / with simpler powers / convex etc. with suitable substitutions, thereby allowing more standard inequalities to be used.  Trying a variety of problems would give useful experience in what to use, though there must be several lists if you search the internet.